# Edit material properties based on material name

Tags: python, materials

I want to process an asset library that contains four assets, one for each season per Blend file. I want to change the material properties for all objects in the Blend file based on the material name.

I have four objects in the scene, which have a suffix per season:
[image]

Now I want to change the material properties based on the season and the material itself, the name of which is the text after the last underscore (e.g. "trunk" or "rock").

Ideally, I want to input a list that contains the materials that should be processed, e.g. (leaf_flowers, leaf). Then, I need to change these properties in the main nodegroup:
[image]

As you can see, input [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlBya.png) corresponds to the AUTUMN property, input [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZOX1.png) to WINTER and input [4] to SPRING.

The changes are as follows:
If the asset contains "_summer", skip it. Summer assets have all 3 properties set by 0 as default.
If the asset contains "_autumn" set input [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlBya.png) to value 1.
If the asset contains "_winter" set input [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZOX1.png) to value 1.
If the asset contains "_spring" set input [4] to value 1.

Note that a typical material looks something like this:
[image]
So it has one node group and this nodegroup is the one that should be affected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like this will work:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import data as D

def find_node_by_inputs(nodes, inputs):
    return next(n for n in nodes if inputs.issubset({i.name for i in n.inputs}))

for mat in D.materials:
    name_parts = mat.name.split('_')
    if len(name_parts) != 5:
        # expecting a different name
        continue
    season = name_parts[-2].upper()
    if season == 'SUMMER':
        continue
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    node = find_node_by_inputs(nodes, {'SPRING', 'AUTUMN'})  # assuming no other node has such two inputs
    node.inputs[season].default_value = 1
```

### v2

I didn't test this code but it probably works. It has a more aggressive heuristic, matching a material and choosing the season if the word is present in the name, regardless of the punctuation:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import data as D

seasons = {'SPRING', 'AUTUMN', 'WINTER'}

def find_node_by_inputs(nodes, inputs):
    return next((n for n in nodes if inputs.issubset({i.name for i in n.inputs})), None)

for mat in D.materials:
    detected_season = None
    name_upper = mat.name.upper()
    for season in seasons:
        if season in name_upper:
            detected_season = season
            break
    else:
        continue
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    node = find_node_by_inputs(nodes, seasons)
    if node:
        node.inputs[detected_season].default_value = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! As for your assumption in the comments, there is only one node group that has multiple input nodes. It has "VEGETATION_" as name.

Comment: @Hologram then it seems you can replace `node = find_node_by_inputs(nodes, {'SPRING', 'AUTUMN'})` with `node = nodes['Group']` or `node = nodes['VEGETATION_']` if I understood you correctly in regards to the name.

Comment: The node name depends on the material, so it's VEGETATION_[Something else], should have mentioned it's like that. I have added the image in the initial question. ;) Similar nodes also appear in other materials, but not in the same material slot so to say.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't change the properties of the material on my end. I also think there needs to be a debugging. You've used the season as being the part of the name with index -2. There are materials with an additional part with underscore. So sometimes the season is index -3, for instance "summer_leaf_small". I think what should happen is that the underscores after _summer_ should be a dash, so that it becomes "[asset name]_summer_leaf-small". with [asset name] = The name of the asset.

Comment: V2 changed the colour (material properties) for the Autumn asset! Nice! But it didn't for the Spring and Winter asset. Since this is part of a commercial addon, I unfortunately won't be able to supply you with a sample. But you are very close now. Is there anything else I can provide you with to help troubleshoot the final issues?

Comment: @Hologram the way this site works is you ask a question in a form specific enough to have a definitive answer but general enough to be useful for other people in the future. So I answered it in a way to show how to set values of a node based on the material name for each material. If you reproduce your problem in a way you can share a .blend file, I don't mind helping specifically, but without that it's hard to guess what's going wrong.

Comment: Yes, I completely understand. I have stripped the file so that I can send it to the e-mail address you've provided in your profile on Blender Stack Exchange. I would very much appreciate your help on this!

Comment: @Hologram I assumed all your materials with a season name in it have the custom group node with inputs with those 3 season names. Since some materials don't, the script errors out upon reaching them. I added a fix to the v2 code.

Comment: Thanks! This is awsome! Really cool that you can do so much with Python :)
Thanks for all your help Markus!